# How do I transfer captured values from my URL into hidden fields on my html form

Tags: php, html-parsing, serverside-javascript

I captured the values using the following javascript code in my html form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

function querySt(ji) {
    dwnstr = window.location.search.substring(1);
    dwnstr = dwnstr.toLowerCase();
    gy = dwnstr.split("&");
    for (i=0;i<gy.length;i++) {
        ft = gy[i].split("=");
        if (ft[0] == ji) {
            return ft[1];
        }
    }
    return "";
}

cust_lat = querySt("lt");
cust_long = querySt("lg");

document.write(cust_lat);
document.write(cust_long);

-->
</script>
```

As you can see I wrote the captured variables to my screen, so I know that the code works.

I need the value of the variables `cust_lat` & `cust_long` put into two hidden fields on my form (`form1`) replacing the default values of `0`

```
type=hidden name=cust_lat><input style="WIDTH: 79px; HEIGHT: 22px" value="0" 
type=hidden name=cust_long><input style="WIDTH: 81px; HEIGHT: 22px" value="0"
```

the result is then passed to `index.php` using the following line:

```
<form method="get" name="form1" action="index.php">
```

Right now the fields are coming through to mysql as the defaults: `0` `0`

I just need to replace these default values with the captured values.

I hope someone can help

Thank you,
Ray Ward

Comment: You forgot to attach your JavaScript code.

Comment: @Tadeck: It was all there, just not properly indented. :)

Comment: @jnpcl I was not seeing this, though - but now I see :) Thx.

Answer (score 0):

$_GET['fieldname'] is the equivalent in php as request.querystring("variable_name") is in asp

Answer (score 0):

give your hidden inputs an id and use
     `document.getElementById('hiddenbox').value="The Value Here"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DOM javascript to set the values. First, specify an id for each of your elements:

`<input type='hidden' name='cust_lat' id='cust_lat'>
<input type='hidden' name='cust_long' id='cust_long'>`

Then, use `document.getElementById('cust_lat').value = whatever;` in your page load javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
<type=hidden name=cust_long value=$_GET['fieldname']>
```

Comment: `/index.php?fieldname=''><script>window.location='http://www.malware.com';</script`

Answer (score 0):

PHP method:

```
<?php
    $lt = (isset($_GET['lt']) && is_numeric($_GET['lt'])) ? (float)$_GET['lt'] : 0;
    $lg = (isset($_GET['lg']) && is_numeric($_GET['lg'])) ? (float)$_GET['lg'] : 0;

    echo <<< HTML
<input type="hidden" name="cust_lat" value="{$lt}">
<input type="hidden" name="cust_long" value="{$lg}">
HTML;
?>
```